# Parse Push Notification for Android in Titanium

Tags: android, push-notification, titanium, parse-platform, titanium-modules

i found solution in iOS with REST API... but... how to do the same in android? anyone solved this? or found kind of workaround?

https://marketplace.appcelerator.com/apps/7889#!overview - This module not available in appcelerator market.

I tried below module also
https://github.com/programmerdave/Titanium-Parse-Module-PreReleases

But this module not worked.

Please help me to solve it.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately Parse uses its own GCM sender id. So it is impossible to use the normal GCM module to fetch a deviceToken and share it with Parse via the REST API, like you would do on iOS. (My previous answer is thus invalid, apologies!)

I created a Titanium module for Android to get Push Notifications working, but it is not yet 100% finished. You do receive the push notifications, but you do not yet get a signal/event when someone clicks on a notification. I am however currently working on this module and hopefully have a complete implementation within a couple of days. (I need it for a project as well).

The module can be found at: https://github.com/timanrebel/Parse Please use version 0.2 which is working. The module is open source and the master is ahead of release 0.2 and includes the new Android SDK from Parse. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Hi i'm getting an error using that module with parse.
When i try to upload the Anroid token generated with this module i get:  ** "code": 114, "error": "deviceToken may not be set for deviceType android" **